# how to clear user session of react-native-app-auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, react-native, session, oauth-2.0, devise

After logged in by the authorization function of the react-native-app-auth lib I couldn't log in with another account until the token expired, that's because the user's session continues to be used.

OBS: I already tried to clear cookies with @react-native-cookies/cookies

I already tried using revoke, but even if the token is revoked, the user session remains in the webview

The closest to a solution I found was using the authorize function passing a logout url to the WEB application

Tried opening my own webview but logout didn't work

About the server:
Devise v4.7.3 + doorkeeper v.5.4.0 is used

The backend uses Ruby 2.7.1 and Rails 6.0.3.3

App:

React Native v0.66.3

react-native-app-auth 6.0.1

```
const config = {
  issuer: API_URL,
  clientId: CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET,
  redirectUrl: CALLBACK_LOGIN,
} as AuthConfiguration
```

```
export const login = async () => {
  try {
    const result = await authorize(config)
    const userData = await requestUserInfo(result.accessToken)
    await AsyncStorage.setItem(USER_INFO, JSON.stringify(userData.data))
    await AsyncStorage.setItem(TOKEN_KEY, result.accessToken)
    await AsyncStorage.setItem(
      TOKEN_EXPIRATION_DATE,
      result.accessTokenExpirationDate
    )
    return true
  } catch (error) {
    return false
  }
}
```

```
export const logout = async () => {
  await AsyncStorage.removeItem(USER_INFO)
  await AsyncStorage.removeItem(TOKEN_KEY)
  await AsyncStorage.removeItem(TOKEN_EXPIRATION_DATE)
}
```

I tried to revoke the token but it didn't work.

I expected the user to be able to switch accounts after logging out

Answer (score 0):

I see no one answwer.
I hope this will help someone because it took me also a lot of time to find a solution but "Bekaxp" posted one on Git Hub.
I use KeyCloak and for me it worked, I added additional params:

```
additionalParameters: { prompt: 'login', }
```

And KeyCloak forces it to provide again user and password
https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth/issues/171#issuecomment-1555876504